# Can Arm GCC infer -mfloat-abi from -mcpu?

Tags: gcc, arm, embedded

For some time now (since [this patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2017-June/476431.html) in 2017), gcc has been able to infer the right `-mfpu` value from `-mcpu`. However, it's not clear to me if the `-mfloat-abi` is also automatically inferred, or needs to be set manually.

The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html#index-mfloat-abi) states somewhat cryptically that "The default [value of mfloat-abi] depends on the specific target configuration."

So, to be specific: if I compile with `-mcpu=cortex-m4`, which by default enables floating-point instructions, will I automatically get `-mfloat-abi=hard`, or at least `softfp`? Or might I end up with the suboptimal `soft`?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is "No."

### `-mfpu`

First let's look at how `-mfpu` is inferred.

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/config/arm/arm.opt#L164-L166

```
mfpu=
Target RejectNegative Joined Enum(arm_fpu) Var(arm_fpu_index) Init(TARGET_FPU_auto) Save
Specify the name of the target floating point hardware/format.
```

The default, `TARGET_FPU_auto` is a defined value of the `arm_fpu` enum:

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/config/arm/arm-tables.opt#L473-L474

```
Enum
Name(arm_fpu) Type(enum fpu_type)
Known ARM FPUs (for use with the -mfpu= option):
```

```
EnumValue
Enum(arm_fpu) String(auto) Value(TARGET_FPU_auto)
```

So `TARGET_FPU_auto` is an FPU enum value which is handled in a few places in  [`arm.cc`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/config/arm/arm.cc).

I won't claim to completely understand how it works -- it involves masking ISA and FPU bitmaps in various places, e.g. [`arm_identify_fpu_from_isa`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/config/arm/arm.cc#L33732).

It's clear enough to me though, that when `opts->x_arm_fpu_index == TARGET_FPU_auto`, some "automatic" selection happens.

### `-mfloat-abi`

Let's compare that to the `-mfloat-abi` default.

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/config/arm/arm.opt#L122-L124

```
mfloat-abi=
Target RejectNegative Joined Enum(float_abi_type) Var(arm_float_abi) Init(TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI)
Specify if floating point hardware should be used.
```

You'll note that the default, `TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI`, is *not* one of the `float_abi_type` enum values:

```
Enum
Name(float_abi_type) Type(enum float_abi_type)
Known floating-point ABIs (for use with the -mfloat-abi= option):

EnumValue
Enum(float_abi_type) String(soft) Value(ARM_FLOAT_ABI_SOFT)

EnumValue
Enum(float_abi_type) String(softfp) Value(ARM_FLOAT_ABI_SOFTFP)

EnumValue
Enum(float_abi_type) String(hard) Value(ARM_FLOAT_ABI_HARD)
```

Instead, it is a `#define`, set by the "target configuration", as you noted from the docs:

```
$ cd gcc/config/arm
$ git grep TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI
arm.h:414:#ifndef TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI
arm.h:415:#define TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI ARM_FLOAT_ABI_SOFT
arm.opt:123:Target RejectNegative Joined Enum(float_abi_type) Var(arm_float_abi) Init(TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI)
freebsd.h:88:#undef TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI
freebsd.h:90:#define TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI ARM_FLOAT_ABI_HARD
freebsd.h:92:#define TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI ARM_FLOAT_ABI_SOFT
linux-eabi.h:36:#undef  TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI
linux-eabi.h:37:#define TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI ARM_FLOAT_ABI_SOFT
linux-eabi.h:62:   GLIBC_DYNAMIC_LINKER_DEFAULT and TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI.  */
linux-elf.h:30:#undef  TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI
linux-elf.h:31:#define TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI ARM_FLOAT_ABI_HARD
netbsd-eabi.h:31:  (TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI == ARM_FLOAT_ABI_SOFT      \
semi.h:35:#ifndef TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI
semi.h:36:#define TARGET_DEFAULT_FLOAT_ABI ARM_FLOAT_ABI_HARD
```

So when not specified on the command line, it is not set to an value indicating "automatic" selection should apply, but rather an actual default option.

And it would appear (this is conjecture), from the output of `grep`, that if you're targeting baremetal or an RTOS (as one would for a Cortex M4), that you might get the default `ARM_FLOAT_ABI_SOFT` from `arm.h`.

Comment: As well, float-abi does not depend on the hardware (directly).  It is the libc ABI for passing floats.  If there is no FPU, the only choice is soft.  However with an FPU you can have either.  So the question is technically impossible giving an answer of no (or maybe if you count CPUs without an FPU).

Comment: @artlessnoise but if you do have an FPU, won't a "hard" float ABI offer superior performance? So, except for compatibility with pre-compiled libraries that were compiled with the "soft" ABI, would you ever want to use anything other than "hard" if you do have an FPU?

Comment: @TedPudlik  Yes, it gives better performance.  But that doesn't mean it can be automatic.  That is all I am saying.

Comment: Also, I think there is a comparison to x86.  If the gcc-arm was a native compiler, it could do this automatically (to create code where build==target).  So, the issue is that the compiler would need to know the libc (and other libraries) deployed to the target machine.  For a native ARM gcc, this would be a good feature to have automated.  But those did not exist so much in the past.